# WaitCursor on sort in DataGridView

Tags: .net, sorting, datagridview, .net-2.0

I am using the standard .Net 2.0 DataGridView with sort mode of automatic on the column.  It is very very slow (which should probably be another question on how to speed it up) but I can't seem to find an event or combination of events that will maintain a WaitCursor while this sort operation is being performed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook "MouseDown" event, check with "HitTest" method where user clicked. If user clicked on the column header set "Cursor.Current = Cursors.Wait" and set some flag "isSorting" to true.

Hook "MouseUp" event, check if "isSorting" flag true, then set "Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default".

**EDIT:**
Use "Sorted" event instead of "MouseUp".
The "MouseUp" is funtionaly, but the "Sorted" is "cleaner" solution.

Comment: I think that MouseUp event would probably occur long before sorting is complete, if is it really slow...

Comment: Yes the mouse up will be completely done before the sort is done.

Comment: That's what I get for assuming.  I just tried it and the mouseup event is not fired until the sort is actually finished.  Well done!

Comment: @Mr. Brownstone - It shouldnt.
The sorting is proceed in UI thread, so the "mouse up" message from windows is proceeded after the sorting done.

Comment: Why not `ColumnHeaderMouseClick`?

Answer (score 0):

Anno 2021, necromancy at it's best :) I was still looking for a way to do this correctly.

**What I tried and what didn't work**

The `CellMouseDown` event is also fired when a user starts dragging (reordering column headers). So that's a compromise.

The `CellMouseClick` event is fired AFTER the `Sorted` event. Since the thread is occupied during the sorting operation and there is no true `SortStart` event, I was starting to think it would be impossible.

**What I ended up doing**

If you're using a `DataTable` as a datasource for your gridview, you'll have to disable automatic sorting for each column.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvUsers.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
}
```

You might be able to do this with
I ended up using the `CellMouseDown` event, the `CellMouseUp` event and two variables `mouseDownColumnIndex` and `sortExpression` as handles on previous sorting actions.

```
    string mouseDownColumnName = "";
    string sortExpression = "";
    private void dgvUsers_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDownColumnName = dgvUsers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
    }

    private void dgvUsers_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left // Obviously
            && e.RowIndex == -1 // column header row index
            && mouseDownColumnName == dgvUsers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText // No drag gesture
        ) {
            dgvUsers.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Task<DataTable> sortAction = Task<DataTable>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DataView dvUsers = ((DataTable)dgvUsers.DataSource).DefaultView;
                string headerText = dgvUsers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
                if (sortExpression == $"{headerText} asc")
                    dvUsers.Sort = $"{headerText} desc";
                else
                    dvUsers.Sort = $"{headerText} asc";
                sortExpression = dvUsers.Sort;
                return dvUsers.ToTable();
            });
            sortAction.Wait();
            dgvUsers.DataSource = sortAction.Result;

            dgvUsers.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

This appears to be faster than default "automatic" sorting.